# Combine two rows into a single series in a line graph (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, duplicate

I am plotting a line graph in Excel and my data is as follows:

[image: Line graph data img]

As you can see there are rows with the same name (an example is highlighted). How do I combine these into the same series? So I will see a line on my graph for each row, but the values of the duplicate rows will be combined, so each point has two values.

Note, I wish to do this in order to avoid any slopes between changes in my graph. What I want is:

[image: Graph with no gradient example img]

If there is a better way to do this please let me know!

**Update:** Scatter graph with duplicate values still showing slopes:

[image: Scatter graph img]

Comment: your sample data starts from x=6, but the chart starts from 1, how? also there are a lot of other lines which disturb reading. Can you please clean up your example?

Answer (score 0):

You've a wrong approach for that, Excel doesn't combine data like that.

What you can do instead: create one series of data including two x points where you want to have the break, and include both y values.

Than insert a scatter plot with straight line, it'll look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added extra columns now where the duplicates need to be but I am still seeing a gradient rather than a vertical. My chart type is 'Scatter with Straight Lines'. Example image added to question - note the red line still has slopes.

Comment: Your series apparently does not use specific X values. Instead it is using the index of each point (1, 2, 3, etc.) for X values. You need to specify X values for each series.

Comment: @JonPeltier: is this a comment to the question or to the answer? The example in the answer DOES USE specific x values.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was replying to the OP's comment on your answer, which does in fact use specific X values. But the OP tried your approach and still did not get the chart he wanted, because I think he still does not use specifically defined X values.